# Is it safe to provide variable to Doctirne Expr static methods (e.g. expr()->eq('p.var', $var))?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

Is it safe to provide variables to Doctirne Expr static methods?

And if it is mandatory to set them as parameters is there an easier way to do so e.g. in the $or->add() method?

So can it be like:

```
$or = $qb->expr()->orx();
if (!empty($sessionId)) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.session_id', $sessionId));
}
if ($user instanceof User) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.user_id', $user->getId()));
}
```

My ugly solution so far is:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$or = $qb->expr()->orx();
if (!empty($sessionId)) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.session_id', ':session_id'));
}
if ($user instanceof User) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.user_id', ':user_id'));
}

$qb->select('up')
    ->from('SCCatalogBundle:UserProject', 'up')
    ->where($or)
    ->OrderBy('up.updated', 'DESC');

if (!empty($sessionId)) {
    $qb->setParameter('session_id', $sessionId);
}
if ($user instanceof User) {
    $qb->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
}

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you should use `setParameter` to avoid SQL-Injection.
I think I is not necessary to set the parameters in that order. Therefore you could write your code like this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$or = $qb->expr()->orx();
if (!empty($sessionId)) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.session_id', ':session_id'));
    $qb->setParameter('session_id', $sessionId);
}
if ($user instanceof User) {
    $or->add($qb->expr()->eq('up.user_id', ':user_id'));
    $qb->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
}

$qb->select('up')
    ->from('SCCatalogBundle:UserProject', 'up')
    ->where($or)
    ->OrderBy('up.updated', 'DESC');


$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: So obvious... thanks for helping me to better understand how Doctrine QB works internally!